# ILMerge.Task Unresolved assembly reference not allowed

Tags: c#, msbuild, task, msbuild-task, ilmerge

I have installed `MSBuild.ILMerge.Task` into my project using `Nuget`.
When i try to build my project , An error comes up :

> Error : Unresolved assembly reference not allowed: ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.

I searched everywhere but couldn't found anything useful...

How to fix this error ?

Comment: Have you got a solution?

Comment: @Jacob sorry dude, i forgot how i fixed it but i guess i had duplicate versions of one DLL and removed it and im not sure

Answer (score 1):

Maybe set the .dll property [private=false] can answer your question.

private means "copy the dll file to directory"